# How can you use iOS 16's UIPasteControl with React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, uiview, uipasteboard

iOS 16 introduces UIPasteControl as a way of avoiding the paste permission dialog appearing when an app programmatically accesses the clipboard contents.

To enable UIPasteControl, its target needs to be set to an object that conforms to UIPasteConfigurationSupporting, so typically a UIResponder like UIViewController or UIView. Then you would ensure the object's pasteConfiguration is set to allow the types you want to paste.

I've got a React Native app so there are no native iOS UIView etc. type objects being used directly.
If, for example, a paste button was to be added to a React Native view, then how can that be hooked up so that its using UIPasteControl?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we consider the latest version of react native, there might we not see the functionality for **UIPasteControl** as per new iOS versions.

for this, I guess we **should create our implementation and export the functionality to react-native to accomplish this requirement**.

If you have hands-on experience with iOS native development and custom native UI views implementation in React Native then you can check out the following blog about the UIPasteControl implementation in native, to implement it natively and export it to React Native.

UIPasteControl(Native) demo : https://blog.kylelanchman.com/how-to-use-uipastecontrol-in-ios-16/